# How to format an arrow as a double line in LibreOffice Draw

Tags: libreoffice

I've searched all options in Line format, and I can make it dotted or change the arrow heads, but it seems impossible in my LibreOffice 5.0.3.2 to draw something as simple as a double line for an arrow, to get something like

[image: double-line arrow]

Comment: I think this question belongs more to super user SE

Comment: @ddnomad This question is perfectly on-topic here. This being said, Envite, [su] does have more LibreOffice expertise than [unix.se]. If you wish, you may flag your question and request for it to be migrated to [su].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LibreOffice Draw has no option for "double lines" yet, as LibreOffice 5.3.

### Custom line styles: Not relevant

[This article](https://help.libreoffice.org/Impress/Loading_Line_and_Arrow_Styles) on LibreOffice Help has noted how to use custom line style from target file.

> To load a line styles file:
>
> 1. Choose **Format** - **Line**, and then click the **Line Styles** tab.
> 2. Click the **Load Line Styles** button.
> 3. Locate the file containing the line styles that you want to load, and then click **OK**. The file has the format [filename].sod.
>
> To save a line styles file, click the **Save Line Styles** button, enter a filename, and then click OK.

While `.sod` file seems to be useful for saving and loading modified line styles, there is no relevant information to create one from new.

### Custom arrow with double lines

There are several workarounds to create an arrow with double lines.

1. **Workaround A (easy)**: Use Unicode character
2. **Workaround B**: Use merged objects

### Workaround A (easy)

Use Unicode character that is found in Unicode Block "Arrows". For example, there is `U+21D2 RIGHTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW` that represents `⇒` character.

1. In Drawing toolbar, select "Text Box" and draw a text box.
2. Type the Unicode character: Press key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, then press <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> and finally press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will insert `⇒`.
3. Finally, adjust size of the character text font and text box.

### Workaround B

Use several drawing objects and merge together to reproduce the arrow with desired style. The following steps will explain for arrow with double lines.

1. In Drawing toolbar, select "Line ends with arrow" and draw the line; Keep the arrow small, such that only the arrow end is visible and the line is hidden underneath.
2. Select the object, **Format** (or right-click menu) ➜ **Lines...** ➜ **Line** tab - **Line Properties**, then change **Width** to `0.04"`; under **Arrow Styles**, change **End style** to "Arrow Concave" and arrow width to `0.30"` (the order of changing is important).
3. In Drawing toolbar, select "Insert line" and draw the line; The length of line is user's choice.
4. Select the object, **Format** (or right-click menu) ➜ **Lines...** ➜ **Line** tab - **Line Properties**, then change **Width** to `0.04"`.
5. Make a copy of line from step 4.
6. Place the lines appropriately with respect to the arrow.
7. Select all objects, then **Modify** (or right-click menu) ➜ **Shapes** ➜ **Merge**.

The following screenshot combo shows how the arrows would look like.

[image: Arrows created by workarounds]

Using either workaround has one drawback: resize does not work like built-in objects.

For example, horizontal resizing of the merged object will cause the arrow end to be stretched instead of only the line becomes longer. Therefore, to have a longer line, the length should be adjusted beforehand (Workaround B, step 3).

Unlike **Group** action that groups objects, the **Merge** action creates merged object that can be resized as whole. However, the only way to revert **Merge** action is "Undo" or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (there is no “Unmerge” menu) at time of edit. Users are advised to *make several copies of objects before merging objects*, in case the end result becomes unexpected and has too many steps to "Undo".

Tested using LibreOffice 5.3 in Xubuntu 14.04.